# Вместо цены на сайте отображаются названия price и basePrice из js, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начал изучать php, честно скажу ранее не работал с js поэтому ни черта не понимаю где ошибка, делаю все как в обучающем курсе? а итог вместо цены названия price и basePrice

```
<?php
$curr = \ishop\App::$app->getProperty('currency');/*подключаем из таблицы цен валюту*/
$cats = \ishop\App::$app->getProperty('cats');/*категории*/
?>
<div class="col-md-7 single-top-right">
  <div class="single-para simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <h2><?=$product->title;?></h2>
    <div class="star-on">
      <ul class="star-footer">
        <li><a href="#"><i> </i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i> </i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i> </i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i> </i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i> </i></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="review">
        <a href="#"> 1 customer review </a>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>

    <h5 class="item_price" id="base-price" data-base="<?=$product->price * $curr['value'];?>"><?=$curr['symbol_left'];?><?=$product->price * $curr['value'];?><?=$curr['symbol_right'];?></h5>
    <?php if($product->old_price): ?><!-- если в продукте есть старая цена -->
    <small><del><?=$product->old_price * $curr['value'];?><?=$curr['symbol_left'];?><?=$curr['symbol_right'];?></del></small><!--старая цена -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?=$product->content;?><!-- выводим описание товара -->
    <div class="available">
      <ul>
        <li>Color
          <select>
            <option>Выбрать цвет</option>
            <?php foreach($mods as $mod): ?>
            <option data-title="<?=$mod->title;?>" data-price="<?=$mod->price * $curr['value'];?>" value="<?=$mod->id;?>"><?=$mod->title;?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
          </select>
        </li>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#currency').change(function(){//при сробатывании change
    //обращаемся к странице и вызываем метод обработки выбранного val
    window.location = 'currency/change?curr=' + $(this).val();
});

$('.available select').on('change', function(){//при изменение цвета включем функцию
    var modId = $(this).val(),
        color = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').data('title'),
        price = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').data('price'),
        basePrice = $('#base-price').text('base');
    if(price){
        $('#base-price').text('price');
    }else{
        $('#base-price').text('basePrice');
    }
    console.log(modId, color, price,);
});
```

Comment: `$('#base-price').text('price');...$('#base-price').text('basePrice');` - вы записываете price и basePrice, что записываете то и отображается

Comment: @InDevX Точно ' ' кавычки, спасибо за умный ответ, на глупый вопрос!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 .... 
if (price)
  $('#base-price').text(price);
} else {
  $('#base-price').text(basePrice);
}
 ....
```

Кавычки не нужны.